# A question construction of rational numbers

Tags: elementary-set-theory, rational-numbers

In $\mathbb{Z}$ we can do addition, substraction and multiplication, but not division.
For example we cannot divide $2$ by $3$ (i.e. the equation $3x=2$ has no solution in $\mathbb{Z}$, because $\dfrac{2}{3}$ is not in $\mathbb{Z}$. To remedy this situation, we will extend the structure $\mathbb{Z}$ to a larger set where  not only we can do addition, substraction and multiplication compatible with the similar operations in $\mathbb{Z}$, but also division.

We would like to invent numbers that will stand for $\dfrac{2}{3}$ e.g. If we attempt to denote $\dfrac{2}{3}$ by the pair $(2,3)$ then we should we have $(2,3)=(4,6)$ and as we know this is not the case. We overcome this difficulty by noting that $\dfrac{a}{b}=\dfrac{c}{d}$ if and only if $ad=bc$. Accordingly,
On set $\mathbb{Z}\times(\mathbb{Z}\setminus\left\{0\right\})$, we define the following relation:

$$(x,y)\equiv (z,t)\iff xt=yz$$

**Theorem 1.** Show that this is an equivalence relation. Define $\mathbb{Q}=\mathbb{Z}\times(\mathbb{Z}\setminus\left\{0\right\})/_\equiv$.

**Theorem 2.** Let $(x,y),(z,t),(x',y'),(z',t')\in\mathbb{Z}\times(\mathbb{Z}\setminus\left\{0\right\})$. If $(x,y)\equiv (x',y')$ and $(z,t)\equiv (z',t')$, then

$i.$ $(xt+yz, yt)\equiv (x't'+y'z', y't')$,

$ii.$ $(xz,yt)\equiv (x'z',y't')$.

Now define

$$[a,b]+[c,d]=[ad+bc, bd],$$
$$[a,b][c,d]=[ac,bd].$$

**Theorem 3.** Show that any $\alpha\in\mathbb{Q}$ can be written as $[a,b]$ for $b>0$ by taking $[-a,-b]$ if necessary.

**My question**: I showed Theorem 1 and Theorem 2 but I couldn't Theorem 3, can you help?

Comment: Show that $(a,b)\equiv (-a,-b)$, and thus that $[a,b]=[-a,-b]$. What's the problem?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin how should I start to prove this?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin It maybe clear but I couldn't start to prove

Comment: How do you prove that $(a,b)\equiv (-a,-b)$? You use the definition of $\equiv$ and you verify that this pair (of ordered pairs) satisfies it.

Comment: You should start by noting that each element of $\mathbb Q$ is of the form $[a,b]$ for some $a\in\mathbb Z$ and some $b\in\mathbb{Z}\setminus\{0\}$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin $(a,b)\equiv (-a,-b)$ iff $a(-b)=b(-a)$, rgiht ? Since we have $a(-b)=b(-a)$, so we get $(a,b)\equiv (-a,-b)$. Can you check?

Comment: $(a,b)\equiv (-a,-b) \iff a(-b)=b(-a)$. The last statement will be true as long as multiplication is commutative.

Comment: @herbsteinberg Okey, thanks

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Let $X=\mathbb{Z}\times(\mathbb{Z}\setminus\left\{0\right\})$ and $(a,b)\in X.$ Then
 
 $$[a,b]=\left\{(x,y)\in X: ay=bx\right\}.$$
 
 Note that
 
 $$[a,b]=[c,d] \iff ad=bc.$$

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos does it proves that each element of $\mathbb{Q}$ is the form  $[a,b]$ for ssome $a\in\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: *By definition*, each element of $\mathbb Q$ is of the form $[a,b]$ for some $a\in\mathbb Z$ and some $b\in\mathbb{Z}\setminus\{0\}$. If it turns out that $b<0$, use the fact that $[-a,-b]=[a,b]$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos in the your first statement I think there is a typo such that it should be ''for some $b$ in set of positive integers, right?

Comment: No. I wrote what I meant to write.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos but the questios says ''Show that any $\alpha\in\mathbb{Q}$ can be write as $[a,b]$ for $b>0$'' that is it says for $b>0$?

Comment: And, as I wrote, if it turns outr that $b<0$, you use the fact that $[a,b]=[-a,-b]$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos okey thanks